# Getting "processXXXX is not responding" when trying to download a file on android

Tags: android, download, playlist

I try to download  a file and save it in internal storage. Here's my code:

```
public class PLSParser {

public String pls_path;
public String pls_content;

public PLSParser () {
    pls_path = "http://rhemafm.serverroom.us:5858/listen.pls";
}

public void getPLSFile () {
    try {
        URL url = new URL (pls_path);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.connect();

        File cacheDir = Environment.getDataDirectory();
        File storage = new File (cacheDir, "temp.dat");

        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream (url.openStream());
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(storage);

        int downloaded = 0;
        byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
        int buffLength = 0;

        while ((buffLength = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
            out.write(buff, 0, buffLength);
            downloaded += buffLength;
        }

        out.flush();
        out.close();
        in.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
}
```

The thing is, it always gets an error. What mistakes have I made?

---

**Edit:**

```
public class PLSParser {

    PLSParser () {}

    void getFile() {
        String url = "http://rhemafm.serverroom.us:5858/listen.pls";
        new DownloadFileAsync().execute(url);
    }

    class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
            int count;

            try {
                URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
                URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
                conexion.connect();

                int lengthOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();

                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/temporary_pls.pls");

                byte data[] = new byte[lengthOfFile];
                long total = 0;

                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                output.flush();
                output.close();
                input.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {}
            return null;

        }
    }
}
```

Still got error from this code... what should I do?

---

**Edit 2:**

```
07-16 09:19:23.260: WARN/dalvikvm(717): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001aa28)
07-16 09:19:23.260: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(717): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
07-16 09:19:23.299: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(717): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.radio.streamingradio/com.radio.streamingradio.Tune_in}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #50: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
07-16 09:19:23.299: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(717):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2401)
07-16 09:19:23.299: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(717):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
07-16 09:19:23.299: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(717):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:116)
07-16 09:19:23.299: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(717):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
07-16 09:19:23.299: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(717):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-16 09:19:23.299: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(717):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-16 09:19:23.299: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(717):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
07-16 09:19:23.299: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(717):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-16 09:19:23.299: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(717):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-16 09:19:23.299: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(717):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
07-16 09:19:23.299: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(717):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
07-16 09:19:23.299: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(717):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-16 09:19:23.299: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(717): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #50: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
07-16 09:19:23.299: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(717):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:438)
07-16 09:19:23.299: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(717):     at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:3433)
07-16 09:19:23.299: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(717):     at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:3513)
07-16 09:19:23.299: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(717):     at android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(LinearLayout.java:1265)
07-16 09:19:23.299: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(717):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:1191)
07-16 09:19:23.299: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(717):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:45)
07-16 09:19:23.299: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(717):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:619)
07-16 09:19:23.299: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(717):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
07-16 09:19:23.299: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(717):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
07-16 09:19:23.299: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(717):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
07-16 09:19:23.299: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(717):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:313)
07-16 09:19:23.299: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(717):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1620)
07-16 09:19:23.299: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(717):     at com.radio.streamingradio.Tune_in.onCreate(Tune_in.java:24)
07-16 09:19:23.299: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(717):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
07-16 09:19:23.299: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(717):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
```

This is my logCat error.

---

**Edit 3:** @lbyrdie: ah, thanks for the solution. I've added the layout attribute and managed to get to the intent. But it still got an error whenever I tried to press the download button. Here's my logCat:

```
07-16 10:19:04.930: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(998): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
07-16 10:19:04.950: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(998): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-16 10:19:04.950: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(998):     at com.radio.streamingradio.PLSParser.<init>(PLSParser.java:17)
07-16 10:19:04.950: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(998):     at com.radio.streamingradio.Tune_in.onClick(Tune_in.java:41)
07-16 10:19:04.950: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(998):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2344)
07-16 10:19:04.950: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(998):     at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4133)
07-16 10:19:04.950: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(998):     at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6504)
07-16 10:19:04.950: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(998):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3672)
07-16 10:19:04.950: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(998):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:882)
07-16 10:19:04.950: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(998):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:882)
07-16 10:19:04.950: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(998):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:882)
07-16 10:19:04.950: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(998):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:882)
07-16 10:19:04.950: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(998):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:882)
07-16 10:19:04.950: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(998):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:882)
07-16 10:19:04.950: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(998):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1712)
07-16 10:19:04.950: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(998):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1202)
07-16 10:19:04.950: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(998):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:1987)
07-16 10:19:04.950: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(998):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1696)
07-16 10:19:04.950: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(998):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1658)
07-16 10:19:04.950: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(998):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-16 10:19:04.950: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(998):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-16 10:19:04.950: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(998):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
07-16 10:19:04.950: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(998):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-16 10:19:04.950: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(998):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-16 10:19:04.950: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(998):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
07-16 10:19:04.950: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(998):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
07-16 10:19:04.950: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(998):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I don't understand it; can someone explain please?

Comment: Please post the error you get.

Comment: I received an error from the emulator. It said that "procesXXXX is not responding...". An usual report for crashed app

Comment: Or, is there a different way to download a file ?? I'd like to know... hehe

Comment: Please post the LogCat output you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this network download on the UI thread, you will freeze your application. Create a background task to do this operation.

```
    theBackground = new Background();                       // Start the background task
    theBackground.execute("");

public static Background theBackground;                 // Background task ID
private class Background extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
```

...etc

Comment: Yes, that is how you should do the read in the background.  I recommend that you take smaller steps with your code and get the various bits like this working. Add some log statements so you can see what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Read the LogCat output closely. Your layout file has a parse error in it. "Binary XML file line #50: You must supply a layout_width attribute."

Answer (score 0):

Here Is the example to download file from server with progressbar

public class main extends Activity {

```
 public static final int DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS = 0;
    private Button startBtn;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        startBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startBtn);
        startBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startDownload();
            }
        });
    }

    private void startDownload() {
        String url = "http://rhemafm.serverroom.us:5858/listen.pls";
        new DownloadFileAsync().execute(url);
    }
    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS:
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading file..");
            mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();
            return mProgressDialog;
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }

class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
        int count;

    try {

    URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
    URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
    conexion.connect();

    int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
    Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + lenghtOfFile);
    FileOutputStream obj;
    InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
    //obj=openFileOutput("some_photo_from_gdansk_poland.jpg", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/yourfile.dat");//obj

    byte data[] = new byte[1024];

    long total = 0;

        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;
            publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }

        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    return null;

    }
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
         Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC",progress[0]);
         mProgressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
        dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
    }
}
```

}

And also use the following permission